# is there a limit to zend framework's fetchAll method?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

so I was trying to use zend's fetchall function to retrieve all 194543 rows within a table...but then nothing came up and when I tried to debug the code, right during the fetchAll line, the debugger would just stop...

is there actually supposed to be a limit to how many rows I can fetch with fetchAll and if so how do I overcome this limitation so that I can fetch everything and put it into a php variable?

Comment: MySQL configuration `max_allowed_packet` may be pertinent.

Comment: Also keep in mind that PHP may run out of memory if you put it all in a variables. Better to retrieve it block by block

Comment: So, also look at PHP's `memory_limit` setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend's fetchAll is a wrapper around PDO's fetchAll, which can be memory intensive, and I've heard of some servers being set up so that it is difficult to create arrays with over 70k entries anyway. The PHP docs do have some [suggestions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) on how to handle this, but I think you may want to re-think this. Why can't you use `fetch` instead?

Comment: Seconded. Fetch_all shouldn't e use in high performance scripts.